# How to unit test chained method call(s) using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am working on a J2EE project which uses the [JIRA's REST Client](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview).
This client returns a Jira `issue` object.
Some of the fields of the `Issue` class are `key`, `self`, `id`, `summary`, etc etc. 
The `self` field here is basically a URI.
For Eg `http://jira.company.com/rest/api/2.0/issue/12345`
I have a use case where I have to retrieve the host from the URI specified above.

I can do that by something like `issue.getSelf().getHost()`.
`issue.getSelf()` returns an object of type 'URI' and to get the host I can simply use the `getHost()` method provided by the `URI` class which returns the host url in `String` format.

Everything works fine.
I am facing problem in unit testing this piece of code using Mockito.
I don't know how to mock chained method calls.

I have the following code snippet.

```
private static final String JIRA_HOST = "jira.company.com";
@Mock private com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue mockIssue;

@Before
    public void setup() {
        when(mockIssue.getSelf().getHost()).thenReturn(JIRA_HOST);
    }
```

Here, I get a `Null Pointer Exception`.

After doing much research, I came to know that I will have to use `@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS) private com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue mockIssue;`.
But this also gives me a `Null Pointer Exception`.

Can someone tell me how can I mock chained method calls.

Comment: Can you create a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with the actual code and test code as we well.

Comment: @StackFlowed, Id you understand closely, the code snippet that I have added to the description covers the `M`, `C` and `V` parts. I don't think it is absolutely necessary to put in all the code just to make it executable. The code snippet is sufficient to answer the question. I don't see a valid reason why any additional code should be provided (and I won't even provide) top answer my question.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS` or whatever that mock annotation is. You just have to mock every object that you want to return in the chain, similar to this:

```
@Mock Issue issue;
@Mock URI uri;

@Before
public void setup() {
    when(uri.getHost()).thenReturn(JIRA_HOST);
    when(issue.getSelf()).thenReturn(uri);
}
```

Comment: That's so lame. The guys at Mockito should create some kind of a @DeepMock. That would be cool.

Comment: Using the above solution, the issue of null pointer persists. I guess refactoring the code could be a solution.

Comment: Is there any reason to start the mock from deepest getter ? We can mock from the beginning as well. For instance, **when (mockIssue.getSelf()).thenReturn(mockUri);**
 **when(mockUri.getHost()).thenReturn(JIRA_HOST):** Are they both same ?

Comment: @YashwinMunsadwala They're equivalent